# Record IP pseudonymously?

Tags: hash, privacy, anonymity

I'd like to be able to ban an IP from my website, but for privacy reasons I would like to not have a record of the IP itself. Hashing the IP would allow for the hash to be brute forced in mere minutes, and salting it would be useless because anyone with access to the bans database would have access to the salt. Is there any way that I could keep some kind of "fingerprint" of an IP, probably involving hashing, that would be feasible to generate on a server but infeasible for an adversary with moderate resources to brute force?

Comment: GdD assumes that you want to keep the banned IP address secret for yourself, but I cannot extract that information from your question. Could you indicate if you are trying to protect the IP address from yourself or to an attacker (or an auditor?)

Comment: In short, I'd drop the last 8 bits from an IPv4 address (IPv6 is different, I could elaborate in an answer). If under DoS attack, make a note of the exact IP address or addresses and block those.

Answer (score 4):

IP addresses aren't usually considered private information, so why you'd want to protect the data I'm not sure. If someone is trying to misuse your system the IP address is a valuable piece of data which you will want to be able to access. Checking IP addresses against a blacklist is an example of where the data is useful. Knowing where the IP address is located geographically could clue you in on who may be attacking you.

In any case you don't have a problem as your goal is to protect the data from yourself, not from others. As you say, if someone can access the database they probably have access to everything. You could store the salt on a different system and access it with some sort of API, but that could be intercepted. The data has little value to an attacker anyway, so why would they bother?

Comment: -1 as this discusses good reasons not to use the above method, instead of answering the actual question.

Comment: @owlstead: There are relatively few IP (v4) addresses total (compared to, for example "random passwords"), so whatever algorithm you use it'd still be relatively easy to simply check every single address. And if you use a really slow algorithm, then it would be a huge performance hit on the app — given that you need to check the IP address against a blocklist for every request.

Comment: @JoelL Agreed, that's already mentioned in my answer. Maybe the -1 was a bit overzealous. Using a secret value may be a good idea to prevent this. Actually using a separate, hardened server could also protect the data *at rest*. Providing real time protection once the server infrastructure hacked is not going to work, but that's *always* the case.

Comment: @owlstead Yeah, sorry — didn't notice that the answer below was also by you.

Comment: *"IP addresses aren't usually considered private information"* YMMV. It depends on the country, person and even context. I personally do consider an IP relatively private information. To make them more anonymous, I see no reason why you can't drop the most identifying bits, depending on the context that may be the last 8 or 16 bits of an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 2):

As GdD postulated, this may not be something you necessarily want to do, but I'll answer regardless of the usability.

Salts are supposed to be public information. You may use a second, static & secret salt, but even without a public salt prevents rainbow table attacks.

Your issue can simply be reduced to the problem of storing passwords, with the notable difference that there is a very limited amount of IP addresses in use. Hence an attacker may always try and brute force the hashed IP address - regardless of the salt.

The best way of protecting the data is to use a PBKDF (PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt) with a public and secret salt. But if the secret salt gets known, it should be possible for an attacker with enough patience to brute force it none-the-less.

Using an (additional) well protected server could help, noting that this will only protect data *at rest*, i.e. if your database gets stolen without the service being available to the attacker.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with any method of masking IPv4 addresses is that there aren't enough of them for it to be meaningful.  Between inefficient allocation and reserved areas, there are only about 2 billion valid addresses.  If an attacker knows your method of masking, they could build up a complete mask->address map in only 2^31 masking operations -- IPv4 addresses can be considered to only provide around 31 bits of security, regardless of what you do to mask them.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be plausible deniability.

Let's say a law enforcement agency is trying to associate an IP you banned with a post that user made on your site and you want to prevent that.

If you have a large enough pool of banned IPs and you have no additional information to associate any of those IPs with a certain post and there's no other information to correlate them (such as timing) then a law enforcement agency won't be able to prove beyond reasonable doubt that any IP on your list was responsible for a particular post.

Comment: Um, is that an answer?